# Resources to understand robot locomotion and Gait functions

Tags: robotics, autonomous

Recently I have been watching Robert Full's talks on TED. He has some obscenely interesting works on robot locomotion. This has intrigued my curiosity and I have been trying to understand his works. I have tried to read many papers on these type of works but I have been unable to understand as I don't have the basics of these things.

Can anyone please direct me to a resource (ebooks, websites, video/audio lectures, forums etc.) where I can understand the basics of Robot Locomotion and gait functions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's one source - Tilden's BEAM/Solarbotics stuff tends to be low-power, low-tech, but the flip side of this is that it is simple. I believe he even had a six-leg gait generator built using a single hex-inverter chip. A quick googling produced

http://faq.solarbotics.net/nvnet.html
http://faq.solarbotics.net/FAQ.html

Also, Valentino Braitenberg's "Vehicles" is a completely amazing book where the starting point is a simple reflexive control system and as the book progresses, increasing complexity is added. Google for 'braitenberg vehicles' and you will also find a simulator related to the book.

[http://www.amazon.com/exec/obidos/ASIN/0262521121/johnwiseman](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0262521121)

Comment: I knew about BEAM robotics. But as you say its overly simple and to make something cool out of such a technology is very hard (see the irony here).Also beam robotics is not as active now. There is no new work done on such a technology.
But I think Vehicles is something that may get me started good

Answer (score 0):

I did some more digging and found out this PDF on MIT OCW. Its the course notes for Underactuated systems. I have not yet read the whole book but it is a nice resource to understand concepts of walking as most of the legged locomotion problems require underactuated control. You can find it here [1](http://ocw.mit.edu/OcwWeb/Electrical-Engineering-and-Computer-Science/6-832Spring-2009/CourseHome/index.htm)